# Query on Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with [Bootstrap accordion](http://plnkr.co/edit/0CLaUzjsHtWocupPQeiV?p=preview)

I want to keep **only one** item active, the others need to be closed. But I can't figured how to do it. The code (link above) shows what I have tried so far.

PS: Ideally as there is a button in each accordion to post the check boxes that have been checked to the next page.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry - never hit Save - Doh! - http://plnkr.co/edit/0CLaUzjsHtWocupPQeiV?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your markup. Your have 3 panel-group elements but your need only one.

For more information see the official documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Fixed code: http://plnkr.co/edit/BxuOCBzgXKPph7Ouqv6k?p=preview

Comment: Is there anyway you can amend the Markup to layout the Accordion horizontally across the page with a nice spacing between them?

Comment: Do you mean indenting source code? It's plunker feature. There is a button in the top right corrner.

Comment: No I mean it was kind of the reason I had the three panel groups - instead of the accordion appearing vertically - I wanted it appearing across the screen horizontally

Answer (score 0):

What was the real problem is that your code had different data-parents. That can't happen if you only want one to be active.

```
data-parent="#accordion1"
```

and

```
 data-parent="#accordion2"
```

should be

```
data-parent="#accordion"
```

You also did have panel groups with the same ID which just cannot happen with your html. You just need to delete two of the panel groups and keep one and you should be fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qHkDwsmswFbVarGDnLgt?p=preview